Issue with Spring Data Neo4j: Fetching Relationships in Both Directions Without Cyclic Dependencies
I’m working with Spring 3.3.2 and Spring Data Neo4j 7.3.2. I have a repository that looks like this:
@Query("MATCH p=allShortestPaths((rootNode:SoftwareComponent {softwareComponent:${"$"}softwareComponent , version:${"$"}version })-[:DEPENDS_ON_SOFTWARE_COMPONENT *1..15]->(dependentNode:SoftwareComponent)) " +
        "WHERE rootNode <> dependentNode " +
        "WITH rootNode AS __sn__, collect(distinct (relationships(p))) AS __sr__, collect(distinct (dependentNode)) AS __srn__ " +
        "RETURN __sn__, __sr__, __srn__")
fun findDependencyByVersion(
        @Param("softwareComponent") softwareComponent: String, @Param("version") version: String
): List<SoftwareComponent>


And I am using the following Node definition:
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator::class, property = "id")
@Node("SoftwareComponent")
class SoftwareComponent(
    @Property(name = "softwareComponent") var softwareComponent: String,
    @Property(name = "version") var version: String,
    @Relationship(type = "DEPENDS_ON_SOFTWARE_COMPONENT", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    @JsonManagedReference
    var dependencies: HashSet<DependsOnSoftwareComponent> = HashSet(),
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)


I am now trying to create another repository to fetch the reverse dependencies (the "consumers") of my SoftwareComponent, i.e., the nodes that depend on my current node. Here is the query I am trying to use:
@Query("MATCH p=(rootNode:SoftwareComponent {softwareComponent: ${"$"}softwareComponent, version: ${"$"}version})<-[r:DEPENDS_ON_SOFTWARE_COMPONENT *0..6]-(s:SoftwareComponent) " +
        "WITH rootNode AS __sn__, collect (relationships(p)) AS __sr__ , collect (nodes(p)) AS __srn__ " +
        "RETURN __sn__, __sr__, __srn__")
fun findConsumerByVersion(
    @Param("softwareComponent") softwareComponent: String, @Param("version") version: String
): List<SoftwareComponent>


The issue I am facing is:

If I add a consumers field with an INCOMING relationship to my SoftwareComponent class, I end up with cyclic dependencies that make the application impossible to load.
I’ve tried creating a second class to represent the SoftwareComponent as a "consumer" (e.g., ReverseSoftwareComponent) and override le field depdencies with an INCOMING relationhsip, but I get an error indicating that the primary label is duplicated.

So my question is: How can I configure Spring Data Neo4j to handle bidirectional relationships without creating cyclic dependencies or duplicating the primary label?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607526/bidirectional-relationships-in-spring-data-neo4j

There are two ways this could be meant:

I end up with cyclic dependencies that make the application impossible to load

The application cannot load because other operations with this repository are slow
As you have already experienced, defining the bidirectional dependency in the database could lead to unexpected performance drops because with a high-connected graph, SDN will fetch "everything" that is reachable.
For your situation, there is a projection feature in place, that allows you to define interfaces that only reflect a sub-set of the defined global model.
You end up in a stackoverflow when rendering the result
This is due to the fact that Jackson will chase every reachable field and SoftwareComponent->SoftwareComponent->Software... is an infinite self-referencing loop. To break out of this, the mentioned answer I gave about the use of Jackson (thanks @cybersam for finding this link already) is still valid.
